# Is there a way to do a "reverse" .=?

Tags: perl

I want to add 0 to the front of `$num`:

```
$num = "0".$num;
```

This works fine, but is there a way to do it with `$num.=` plus some sort of operator or something to tell it to concatenate in the opposite way?  Or any other way to do it, in general?

Comment: I believe the shorthand operator `.=` only appends.

Comment: You could also do `$num = "0$num";`, or `$num =~ s/^/0/;`

Comment: sounds like we should find another random symbol and add this to the language! Maybe `$num <.= "0"`

Comment: @aschepler could you please explain the latter one?

Comment: @jamylak, seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: @SteveP. it's a regex substituion that replaces the beginning of the text (`^`) with `0`

Comment: @jamylak, I thought that stood for "begins with"?

Comment: @SteveP. That's what it *implies* usually, when searching for something, but it actually matches the beginning of the text, in multiline mode it matches the beginning of each line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Assignment operators don't work that way.

```
$a .= "foo";
```

...always means something similar to

```
$a = $a . "foo";
```

There is no operator for "concatenate these strings and reverse the order", and so there is no corresponding assignment operator.

Comment: So there's no way to: `$a .= "foo" . $a`? Just want to clarify, I don't want the string reversed, I just want the order of the two added expressions to be reversed.

Comment: If I give $a a value 'bar', `$a .= "foo" . $a` would leave $a containing 'barfoobar', because the precedence of `.` beats the precedence of `.=` (assignment operators have the same precedence as regular assignment)

Comment: I understand that, I'm currently using: `$num = "0".$num;` I just wanted to know if there was a way to do what I just wrote, but using some sort of `inverse operator` for `.=`

Comment: Ah OK. Then no, I'm afraid assignment operators don't work like that. For any operator "op", `$x op= $y` is just syntactic sugar for `$x = $x op $y` -- never for `$x = $y op $x`.

Answer (score 1):

Insert `0` in front of `$num`,

```
$num =~ s|^|0|;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no prepend operator, but you can do this.

Assume `$num` is not defined yet.

```
my $num = '0';
$num .= expr-that-generates-the-number;
```

So you're effectively prepending `0` to the variable without having to type the variable twice.

Answer (score -2):

If your concern is to do this frequently, you could dump the string elements into an array and then reverse it? But you won't necessarily be reducing the amount of code, but may be easier to keep track of everything.

```
$array = array();

array_push ( $array , "test" );
array_push ( $array , 0 );

$array = array_reverse( $array );

echo implode( "" , $array );
```

Comment: I don't want the reverse string.  I want to do something like this: `$a .= "foo" . $a`.  Not the reverse, I just want to two expressions to add in the opposite order.

Comment: Steve, can't you just use `$a = 'foo' . $a` then?